# Draw a series of rectangles using actionscript3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, drawing, flash

I am trying to draw a series of rectangles using `actionscript3`.i retrieve my information i mean position using `XML`

```
<onlineTrain>
  <sensor>

    <xlocation>13</xlocation>
    <ylocation>307</ylocation>

  </sensor>
  <sensor>

    <xlocation>121</xlocation>
    <ylocation>301/ylocation>

  </sensor>
</onlineTrain>
```

So i put these values inside `foreach`:

```
for each(var element:XML in xml.sensor)
{
    var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
   addChild(sp);
  sp.x =element.xlocation;
  sp.y = element.ylocation;
  var g:Graphics = sp.graphics;
  g.lineStyle(1, 0x0000FF);
  g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 60, 15);

}
```

But it doesn't work.any ideas will be appreciated .i am so new in AS3

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What isn't working? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sp.x = int(element.location[0]);
sp.y = int(element.location[1]);
```

Or you can see this example [xml example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#includeExamplesSummary)